# ReferenceError: EE is not defined error on page with Grids

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid

I am on EE 2.7.2

Here is my channel form tag that has grid data

```
{exp:channel:form
    channel="xxxxx"
    class="form-horizontal"
    datepicker="no"
    dynamic_title="[email]"
    edit_member="yes"
    entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"
    error_handling="inline"
    id="basic_information"
    include_assets="yes"
    include_jquery="yes"
    member_id="CURRENT_USER"
    rules:profile_name="required"
    rules:user_provided_address="required"
    return="/xxxxx/"
}
```

In the page I am using Grid, I have tried doing various permutations of `include_assets` and `include_jquery` to make an JS error go away because it blocks Grid from working properly(Grid relies on JS)

**CASES**

- **`include_assets="yes"`, `include_jquery="yes"`**

I have this JS error in the console

```
ReferenceError: EE is not defined
```

This is the script being included

```
 http://xxxxx.com/?ACT=7&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,sortable,button,dialog&plugin=markitup,toolbox.expose,overlay,tmpl&file=cp%2Fsort_helper,cp%2Fgrid,underscore&v=1381722060&include_jquery=y
```

- **`include_assets="yes"`, `include_jquery="no"`**

I have this JS error in the console

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

This is the script being included

```
http://xxxxx.com/?ACT=7&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,sortable,button,dialog&plugin=markitup,toolbox.expose,overlay,tmpl&file=cp%2Fsort_helper,cp%2Fgrid,underscore&v=1381722060

http://xxxxx.com/themes/third_party/mx_lonestar/js/jquery.mx_lonestar.min.js
```

- **`include_assets="no"`,`include_jquery="yes"`**

I have this JS error in the console

```
ReferenceError: EE is not defined
```

This is the script being included

```
http://xxxxx.com/?ACT=7&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,sortable,button,dialog&plugin=markitup,toolbox.expose,overlay,tmpl&file=cp%2Fsort_helper,cp%2Fgrid,underscore&v=1381722060&include_jquery=y
```

- **`include_assets="no"`,`include_jquery="no"`**

I have this JS error in the console

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

This is the script being included

```
http://xxxxx.com/?ACT=7&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,sortable,button,dialog&plugin=markitup,toolbox.expose,overlay,tmpl&file=cp%2Fsort_helper,cp%2Fgrid,underscore&v=1381722060

http://xxxxx.com/themes/third_party/mx_lonestar/js/jquery.mx_lonestar.min.js
```

**NOTE**: There is a jquery script at the bottom of the page included

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is there any solution to this problem? I have tried to debug this for a week already but to no avail.

Comment: It's likely to be caused by the JS that gets embedded directly into the page. Are you able to provide a link to a page that produces the error? If not, a copy/paste of the generated HTML (view source) should suffice to help us debug the problem.

Comment: just for sure - user which u use for test, can post and edit entries in this channel?

Answer (score 1):

*There is a jquery script at the bottom of the page include*

I believe this is the reason - you need to load your jquery library before other scripts.

p.s. [this answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/safecracker-matrix-jquery-declaration-and-object-has-no-method-markitup) has good solution what you can do in this case

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't address the initial issue of `EE` not being defined. Check http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/14694/156 for an answer to a similar question (though it may not solve this case).

Answer (score 0):

**Add include_jquery="no" to the tag and move your jQuery from the footer to the header.**

From this [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2195167/135935)...

"make sure that you are not loading any plugins before you load jQuery. Plugins extend the "$" object, so if you load a plugin before loading jQuery core, then you'll get the error you described."